# Intercepting heapq

Tags: python, heap

I want to use Python's `heapq` module. However, I need to keep track of which index every value is set to.

So I wrote

```
class heap(list):       
    def __init__(self,xs):
        super(heap,self).__init__(xs)
        self._index_table = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(self)}

    def __setitem__(self,i,v):
        print(i,v)
        super(heap,self).__setitem__(i,v)
        self._index_table[v] = i

    def append(self,x):
        super(heap,self).append(x)
        self._index_table[x] = len(self)-1

from heapq import heapify, heappush, heappop, _siftdown, _siftup

h = heap([4,3,2,1])
heapify(h)
heappush(h,12)
print(h)
print(h._index_table)
```

And this prints

```
[1, 3, 2, 4, 12]
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 0}
```

`heapify` and `heappush` have modified the entries in my list circumventing my attempts to catch all the assignments.

Why is this happening? Is there a way around this? Is there still a way I can use the `heapq` module and still keep track of which index each value corresponds to?

EDIT:

Looks like my code had a `heapify(h)` line I didn't have in my original post. Fixed this.

Comment: I don't have specific advice, but it looks like there are list modifying methods that are being called by `heapify` and `heappush` that you're not overloading.  Have you tried finding the source code of the `heapq` module to see what list methods it calls?

Comment: @SamMussmann [heapq.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py) looks like it's mostly using simple assignment and append. But I actually just noticed towards the bottom it imports a [C implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py#l343). The python code itself looks like it should play nice with my code...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While reading [`heapq`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py) source's code, I noticed as @math4tots did that it was importing a C implementation. So I ran the following to prove whether it is using the python source (which would call methods from `list` that are overloadable), or it's using the C implementation that uses compiled methods for lists:

```
>>> class heap(list):        
...     def __init__(self,xs):
...         super(heap,self).__init__(xs)
...         self._index_table = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(self)}
...     
...     def __setitem__(self,i,v):
...         print("SETITEM")
...         print(i,v)
...         super(heap,self).__setitem__(i,v)
...         self._index_table[v] = i
...     
...     def append(self,x):
...         print("APPEND")
...         super(heap,self).append(x)
...         self._index_table[x] = len(self)-1
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> h = heap([4,3,2,1])
>>> heapify(h)
>>> h
[1, 3, 2, 4]
>>> h._index_table
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 0}
>>> heappush(h,42)
>>> h
[1, 3, 2, 4, 42]
>>> h._index_table
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 0}
```

it does not printout a single string… which means it does not use the python sources we were looking at, but definitely the compiled version.

So your code is unlikely to work as is…

Reading the C source code of the [`heapq module`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a6fc2405fdbc/Modules/_heapqmodule.c#l243) proves us right: the [`_siftup`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a6fc2405fdbc/Modules/_heapqmodule.c#l51) function is using `PyList_SET_ITEM()` to get values from the list overriding any attempt to overload the method.

Though, all hope is not lost, reading the C source code further on, made me discover that actually the C module [does not export](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a6fc2405fdbc/Modules/_heapqmodule.c#l386) the `_sitf*` functions implementing the heapq algorithms. So I've looked at the following, as a double check:

```
>>> heapq.heapify
<built-in function heapify>
>>> heapq._siftup
<function _siftup at 0x10b36ab00>
```

Which proved me right!

So, you can always reimplement the [`heapify()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py#l171) and [`heappush()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py#l132) functions which are about a couple of lines long, by using the [`_siftup()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py#l287) and [`_siftdown()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/heapq.py#l234) functions from heapq module that are not shadowed by the C code.

so here would be a take at reimplementing it:

```
import heapq

class HeapQueue(list):
    def __init__(self,xs):
        super(HeapQueue,self).__init__(xs)
        self._index_table = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(self)}
    def __setitem__(self,i,v):
        super(HeapQueue,self).__setitem__(i,v)
        self._index_table[v] = i
    def append(self,x):
        super(HeapQueue,self).append(x)
        self._index_table[x] = len(self)-1
    def push(self, x):
        self.append(x)
        heapq._siftdown(self, 0, len(self)-1)
    def heapify(self):
        n = len(self)
        for i in reversed(range(n//2)):
            heapq._siftup(self, i)
```

results:

```
>>> h = HeapQueue([4,3,2,1])
>>> print(h._index_table)
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 0}
>>> h.heapify()
>>> print(h)
[1, 3, 2, 4]
>>> print(h._index_table)
{1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3}
>>> h.push(42)
>>> print(h._index_table)
{1: 0, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3, 42: 4}
>>> print(h)
[1, 3, 2, 4, 42]
>>>
```

my guess is that you wouldn't want to keep that `heapify()` method, but instead make it as part of the constructor, and think through a nicer interface for your own Heap Queue class. I've only did it as proof of concept for that idea.

HTH